# How can I enforce a numeric condition in the value of an EditText?

Tags: java, android

How can I put condition in my EditText, the EditText is for age and should be a number.

So I want:

1. put condition it is allow to the user to insert number from 1 to 100
2. if the user insert more than 100, the EditText will be automatically 100
3. retrieve the EditText value as string

This is my code:

```
package mm.app.pkg;

import android.app.Activity;     import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CreateNewForm extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener, InputFilter         {


Button Browse;
ImageView  CasePic;
Spinner CaseDurationH, CaseDurationM;
TextView tesst;
RadioGroup GenderSelection;
EditText CaseName, CaseClothes, CaseMoreInfo, CaseAge;
Button Next;
//For Browsering Picture 
 private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.create_new_form);

//To Call initializer Function 
initializer();

//j list

// 1-For Uploading Picture
Browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
        // select a file
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }
});

// 1-Name
final MyCase case1 = new MyCase();
case1.setName(CaseName.getText().toString());

// 2-Gender For Group Radio
GenderSelection.clearCheck();
GenderSelection.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
         switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.radio0:
            case1.setGender("Male");
            break;
        case R.id.radio1:
            case1.setGender("Female");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
     });

   //3-Age
   String age = CaseAge.getText().toString();

   private int min, max;

   public void InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
    this.min = min;
    this.max = max;
}

  public void InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
    this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
    this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
}


     public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {  
       try {
        int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
        if (isInRange(min, max, input))
            return null;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) { }     
    return "";
   }

    private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
    return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
   }
     CaseAge.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "100"))};


   /*int tstnum =case1.getAge();
   tesst.setText(tstnum); */

    //4-Duration Time
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
    this, R.array.feedbacktypelist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
   adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  CaseDurationH.setAdapter(adapter); 


  //5-Case Clothes
 case1.setClothes(CaseClothes.getText().toString());

 //6-Case More Information
 case1.setMoreInfo(CaseMoreInfo.getText().toString());

 //Move to 2nd form page
 Next= (Button)findViewById(R.id.Next2);
 Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) { 
        switch (v.getId()) { 
        case R.id.Next2:
            try
            {
                 Intent k = new Intent(CreateNewForm.this, CreateNewForm_2.class);

                 startActivity(k);

            }catch(Exception e){

            }

            break;

        }
    }






   });



   //Spinner
   CaseDurationH.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      int i =CaseDurationH.getSelectedItemPosition();
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
          int i = CaseDurationH.getSelectedItemPosition();

         if(i==2){
             CaseDurationM.setEnabled(false);
        }
         String str = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

         if(str.equals("hr0"))
                {
            CaseDurationM.setEnabled(true);
            }

         if(str.equals("hr1"))
                {
            CaseDurationM.setEnabled(true);
             }


           if(str.equals("hr2"))
                   {
               CaseDurationM.setEnabled(false);  
               }
       }
       public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       } });

 }


 // To initialize the variables 
 private void initializer() {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   //This information will be filled by a user
           //CasePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
           CaseName= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseNm);
           GenderSelection= (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
           CaseAge= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseaage);
           tesst= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
           CaseDurationH= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Shr);
           CaseDurationM= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Smin);
            CaseClothes= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseClothes);
            CaseMoreInfo= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseMrInfo);
            CasePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.casepic);
            Browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browseCasePic);
  }


//For Uploading Picture
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
   if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
        }
     }
}

 //For Uploading Picture
 public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
   Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
   int column_index = cursor
        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
 }


 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
      long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
      Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
 }


 }
```

Comment: what about `InputFilter` and `NumberKeyListener`? you should also probably set the `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER` to accept only numbers. This is your case btw http://tech.chitgoks.com/tag/edittext/ .

Comment: i try with this code but it is give me error at `CAge.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "100");`

Comment: :) try et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "100")});

Comment: I dont see you created the class `InputFilterMinMax`

Comment: i implement it, `public class CreateNewForm extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener,InputFilter`   is not enough?

Comment: @SergeyBenner what should i do right now ?

Comment: It would be better if you implement an InputFilterMinMax in a separate say inner class otherwise you will have to create new constructors for the activity which I don't think would be logically correct. Just do as they do in the example and set the `et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "100")});` in this way because again the InputFilterMinMax is a class with its own constructors being used for the `setFilters()` method of the EditBox.

Comment: can you explain more, because i already do like what they do, except that i do not know where should put `et.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "100")});`

Comment: edit your code and show the class where you do it all.

Comment: @SergeyBenner Sorry for being late, now can you tell me what is the error?

Comment: well the whole class is a mess. give me a few minutes to set it.

Comment: sorry about it, i really appreciate your effort, sorry for bothering you,waiting your edit :$

Comment: I've posted your class re-factored as an answer see if it will work this way.

Answer (score 0):

First - it's not good idea to make those kind of checks manually - see, if the component that you're using - ExitText supports some sort of built-in validators.

Then - all after all, if you want to code the validation yourself - here's an example:

```
EditText CAge;
CaseAge= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caage);
String age = CaseAge.getText().toString();
  if (Integer.parseInt(age) < 1) {
      //handle invalid value
     } else {
         if ((Integer.parseInt(age) > 100){
            CaseAge.setText("100");
              }
            }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: when i run your code, it is give me a message "the project is stopped unexpectedly " i do not know what is the wrong with it!

Comment: also how can check it automatically, i will appreciate it if you give me another solution.

Comment: @android dev. - I don't know why your projects stops like that. Can you debug it? Does it throw any exceptions? Is it in my snippet?

Comment: @android dev. - regarding second question: it's been a while since I haven't done anything for Android and I have to look through the reference of the api... But I've been using other java gui libraries, that have a build in mechanism, using which a registered and setup(!!) validator goes over the input and performs its check upon particular event.

Comment: yeah it is give me the same error, help me, what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

try out below code which implements textWatcher which listens the text event of edittext so that you can control user while typing the text.
You can get value of editText by

```
String value= edt.getTest().toString();
```

and

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {


             }
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                 previous_text=s.toString();
                }
                  public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {   
                Integer.parse
                      int val= Integer.parseInt(s.toString());
                       if(val>100)
                            {
                             edt.setText("100");
                            }
                          if(val<0)
                            {
                             edt.setText("");
                            }

             }
               });
```

Comment: is there is any way to a void text watcher?? i do not want to use it,please help me

Comment: i have 2 little things does not work : 1- i want my max number =100 but with the code it is give me max number = 99 2- i want if the user insert number more than 100 then the edit text will be automatically 100.  i worked with my code that @Sergey Benner fix it

Answer (score 0):

Here is your class fixed without imports insert your imports and try it out.
hope it helps.

EDIT: a simplified version of the activity to text with one EditText and the InputFilter class and it sure is working.

```
public class CreateNewForm extends Activity {
    EditText  CaseAge;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout
                 ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        CaseAge = new EditText(this) ;
        CaseAge.setWidth(69);
        ll.addView(CaseAge);
        setContentView(ll);
        CaseAge.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(1, 100)});
    }
    class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {
        private int min, max;
        public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            try {
                int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
                if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                    return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            }
            return "";
        }

        private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
            return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class CreateNewForm extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    Button Browse;
    ImageView CasePic;
    Spinner CaseDurationH, CaseDurationM;
    TextView tesst;
    RadioGroup GenderSelection;
    EditText CaseName, CaseClothes, CaseMoreInfo, CaseAge;
    Button Next;
    //For Browsering Picture
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    private String selectedImagePath;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.create_new_form);
//To Call initializer Function
        CaseName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseNm);
        GenderSelection = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        CaseAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseaage);
        tesst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        CaseDurationH = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Shr);
        CaseDurationM = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Smin);
        CaseClothes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseClothes);
        CaseMoreInfo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.caseMrInfo);
        CasePic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.casepic);
        Browse = (Button) findViewById(R.id.browseCasePic);

        final MyCase case1 = new MyCase();
        case1.setName(CaseName.getText().toString());

        GenderSelection.clearCheck();
        GenderSelection.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch (checkedId) {
                    case R.id.radio0:
                        case1.setGender("Male");
                        break;
                    case R.id.radio1:
                        case1.setGender("Female");
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        Browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                // select a file
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                        "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
            }
        });

        CaseAge.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(1, 100)});
        CaseAge.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
//String age = CaseAge.getText().toString(); //not used anywhere

// CaseAge.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{ new InputFilterMinMax("1", "100")}); //this one can be used too
        //4-Duration Time
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.feedbacktypelist, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        CaseDurationH.setAdapter(adapter);
        case1.setClothes(CaseClothes.getText().toString());
        case1.setMoreInfo(CaseMoreInfo.getText().toString());
        Next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Next2);
        Next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch (v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.Next2:
                        try {
                            Intent k = new Intent(CreateNewForm.this, CreateNewForm_2.class);
                            startActivity(k);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        //Spinner
        CaseDurationH.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
            int i = CaseDurationH.getSelectedItemPosition();

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                int i = CaseDurationH.getSelectedItemPosition();

                if (i == 2) {
                    CaseDurationM.setEnabled(false);
                }
                String str = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();

                if (str.equals("hr0")) {
                    CaseDurationM.setEnabled(true);
                }

                if (str.equals("hr1")) {
                    CaseDurationM.setEnabled(true);
                }
                if (str.equals("hr2")) {
                    CaseDurationM.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    //For Uploading Picture
    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                               long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    class InputFilterMinMax implements InputFilter {

        private int min, max;

        public InputFilterMinMax(int min, int max) {
            this.min = min;
            this.max = max;
        }

        public InputFilterMinMax(String min, String max) {
            this.min = Integer.parseInt(min);
            this.max = Integer.parseInt(max);
        }


        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            try {
                int input = Integer.parseInt(dest.toString() + source.toString());
                if (isInRange(min, max, input))
                    return null;
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            }
            return "";
        }

        private boolean isInRange(int a, int b, int c) {
            return b > a ? c >= a && c <= b : c >= b && c <= a;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, it is work, you are Awesome, really thank you! But there is a little thing, i want my max number = 100 ,but when i run it, the max number is 99, how can i change it?

Comment: It's working perfectly this way `CaseAge.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilterMinMax(1, 100)});` I've just tested it. Perhaps you have some kind of `android:maxLength` limitations set in the layout XML there.

Comment: I have added the `CaseAge.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` just in case you need it.

Comment: no,my XML is : `<EditText
        android:id="@+id/caseaage"
        android:layout_width="61dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="175dp"
        android:layout_y="195dp" 
        android:inputType="number"
         />`

Comment: `CaseAge.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);` what this statement mean ? and should i just copy this statement?i mean no other statement change in the code?

Comment: no you shouldn't because you already have `android:inputType="number"`. As I said I've just tested the code on Android 2.2 and it's working fine and it is possible to enter 100.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8413/discussion-between-sergey-benner-and-android-dev)

Comment: @androiddev. you should try first the simplified version activity with on edittext box and the inputfilter and see if it works.